# custom TextView is not showing text but shows only background

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an strange behavior of TextView *it beats me* how can I figure out a solution to this issue.
I have a layout

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/them_avatar_spacer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <org.slabs.fc.chatstarter.ui.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/them_avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4.0dip"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/black_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/chat_name_fontsize"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="63.0dip"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:background="@drawable/selectable_balloon_left"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_body_line_spacing"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:text="Every message text comes here"
                android:textColor="@color/black_heavy"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/chat_text_msg_fontsize"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chat_time"
                android:layout_width="60.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60.0dip"
                android:text="12:15"
                android:textColor="@color/black_lightest"
                android:textSize="@dimen/chat_timestamp_fontsize"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It gives me desired layout in a **Design** option of XML editor, as shown

[image: desired layout]

But when I run the App the TextView with id `chat_text` is not showing and I get a result like below,

[image: weird results]

Then I tried to create a custom TextView I simply created one as

```
public class ChatThemTextView extends TextView {

    public ChatThemTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ChatThemTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ChatThemTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins = ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.class.cast(getLayoutParams());
        int margin = 5;
        margins.topMargin = margin;
        margins.bottomMargin = margin;
        margins.leftMargin = margin;
        margins.rightMargin = margin;
        setLayoutParams(margins);
    }
}
```

At this point other issue came out which is when I add the first message I don't get anything but when I add the second message I get the background but TextView is still not showing as shown here

[image]

You all see what is expected how the output comes, any help is appreciated...

#### Update

ViewHolder is just simple

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

adapter class goes here

```
public class ChatMessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private List<ChatMessage> mMessageList;
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean isMe = false;
    public ChatMessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<ChatMessage> mMessageList){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mMessageList = mMessageList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.chat_them_container, null);
        return new ThemMessageHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ThemMessageHolder messageHolder = (ThemMessageHolder) holder;
        messageHolder.mMessageTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
        messageHolder.mSentAtTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getSentAt());
        Log.e("MSG_TEXT", mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }

    public void clearData() {
        mMessageList.clear(); //clear list
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

### important

I get the Sting value at

```
Log.e("MSG_TEXT", mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
```

but TextView is not showing that String...

.gitignore is

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

and settings.gradle is just

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: If you guys don't mind then please visit [this link](https://github.com/arshadalisoomro/ChatStarter) to source of the app

Comment: Can you post any error log?

Comment: No errors, app works fine but issue with TextView

Comment: you may check out source at link mentioned above

Comment: i think your viewholder issue. you are extending normal ViewHolder on your adapter. but you are casting it your customviewholder. try to extend your customviewholder on your recyclerview. Like public class ChatMessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ThemMessageHolder>. i am not sure. but try this.

Comment: Ok I will update...

Comment: see update please

Comment: OK. i am talking about, onBindViewHolder() method. @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ThemMessageHolder messageHolder = (ThemMessageHolder) holder;
        messageHolder.mMessageTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
        messageHolder.mSentAtTextView.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getSentAt());
        Log.e("MSG_TEXT", mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());
    }     here you are casting .

Comment: your viewholder class doesn't know about your layout. that's why it is not showing your text.

Comment: The TextView with id chat_text has height and width wrap_content. I doubt you are setting empty text to the TextView. Can you post the code of your adapter class?

Comment: @SureshKumar see update please

Comment: Copying your code to build another application makes it work perfectly... which device are you testing on by the way?

Comment: QMobile Noir M350, why this issue comes, how to solve it

Comment: One more thing, you are supposed to commit `settings.gradle`. It is missing from your repo and the `.gitignore` file too.

Comment: Sorry that is just bad of me I forgot that to commit there, but those are simple see update

Comment: @ArshadAli why are using a custom textview?

Comment: @VipulAsri in my case I first tried the default TextView widget, but it was not shown, then I tried a custom TextView that only showed the background, clearly there was no need of custom TextView but I was trying to get the work done in one or other way that is why I used custom TextView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may change:

```
View rootView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.chat_them_container, null);
```

To:

```
View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_them_container, parent, false);
```

It will respect the `LayoutParams` of its parent, and hence fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks Man! I'll award the __Bounty__ once I get rid of ___You may award your bounty in 21 hours___ message

Comment: Thanks again for this help!

Comment: Sorry Man! sorry for late response __Happy coding__

Comment: Thanks! Same to you.